# html5: enable on screen keyboard for a div

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile

Let's say we have a div:

```
<div>Random text</div>
```

Now when I tap on this div on mobile/tablet it should bring up on screen keyboard so that I can type. I would like to handle the keys typed using standard events. Any idea how I can bring up the on screen keyboard?

Comment: Is your goal for the text to be editable? Or just to bring up the keyboard and the text be unchangeable?

Comment: I am working on nutty.io it has terminal emulator which works in browser. The terminal emulator is not an input or textarea so I am not able to use keyboard on mobile devices. So I was wondering how to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Contenteditable](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-editable-content/) attribute of HTML5 on div.

Please see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFze/4/)

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="div1"><strong>Click on me to edit the content.</strong>
    Have a look I am a div not a textbox or textarea and I have used
    <strong>"contenteditable"</strong> 
</div>

</br>

<div>Click on me to edit the conetct, 
     <strong>sorry I am not editable</strong>
</div>
```

Click on the first div you can also edit the content and also attach an event to it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hi-jack an textarea or input field (whichever fits your needs best).

```
div.onclick = focus textarea
textarea.onkeyup = change div content
... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `<textarea>` element rather than a normal div. You can apply some CSS to make it look less like a generic input box. Since it is selectable, the on screen keyboard will automatically appear.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: The text will be editable with this method. If you apply `disabled` or `readonly` to the `<textarea>` to prevent it from being edited, the keyboard will not activate on touch. I'm not sure if that is the OP's goal (being able to edit the text).